# Is there a Java web framework that can reliably produce XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Tags: java, xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

I'm starting a Java project where the client has mandated the use of XHTML 1.0 Strict. JSF Facelets, being XHTML-based seemed a good option at first, but I've found that they cannot be made to produce XHTML Strict, and this is considered [a very low priority issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-404) by the community.

Are there other Java frameworks that support rendering as XHTML Strict? What about the JSTL tag libraries?

Comment: I know Struts 1.3.x tags can render xhtml, but as for Strict?, I just declare its definition on each page (to be safe).

Comment: Well, anything different from JSF and GWT (and the likes) do not produce any HTML at all from its core components. For JSP there are taglibs that may or may not produce strict html, but that would depend on the particular taglibs.

Comment: that aside - a requirement for strict is not something rather reasonable. What if the next thing they'd want is to make it work on IE6 :)

Comment: @Bozho make it work on IE6 would probably be the opposite of what's needed to validate as strict :-)

Comment: @Bozho: The taglibs are pretty much part of the core components for JSF at least - I don't think you can actually use it without them. And in general, I'd rather not go back to using JSPs with scriptlets. So yeah, I'm looking for a framework and tag library (they do seem to go hand in hand) that can be used to reliably produce XHTML Strict. As you've mentioned yourself: all it takes is one wrong attribute or tag placement in a core tag and you've lost.

Answer (score 5):

I'll extend my comment a bit here. JSF is not a regular web-framework. It is a component-based web-framework. So are GWT, Vaadin, Echo and the likes. With them one cannot easily get around if they don't produce XHTML strict. (well, you can change the Component/Renderer in JSF, if you like)

On the other hand, frameworks like Spring-MVC, Struts, Grails, etc. are action-based web-frameworks. They do not have components as intrinsic parts. Yes, they do provide convenient tag libraries, but you can go without them, if they happen to be unable to produce strict xhtml. For example you can use `<form:input>`, but you can also use `<input type="text" />` and just set the proper `name` and `value`.

Most of the action-based frameworks rely on JSTL for their flow-control in the view (JSP). So no scriptlets. But JSTL itself does not render any markup. So you can use JSTL + your hand-written markup to generate XHTML strict.

The tag libraries that will be used is a different story. For example if you want a calendar, you can use a taglib, and it might not render proper xhtml. But you can also a jQuery calendar - the difference won't be huge for an action-based framework.

That said, I have experience with Spring-MVC and Grails, and you can use them - they allow fine-grained control on the generated markup.

Comment: Just curious: is it easy to bind actions without Spring MVC's `<form:form>` tag? Does it not generate the `name` attribute? (which is namely invalid as per XHTML Strict)

Comment: `<form id="command" action="/account/login" method="post">` - generated form from my recent project. So it does not generate a name. Even if it did, you could use `<form>` and set an `action` and `method` - they are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for Spring Web MVC 2.0.x indicate that the associated tag libraries produce HTML4.0.1/XHTML1.0 valid markup. That might be a good starting point, as I'd expect 2.5 and probably even 3.0 to support this as well.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html

Comment: There's no point in linking to ancient versions. Here's the current release: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: XHTML 1.0 Transitional or XHTML 1.0 Strict? There's a big difference, and I'd hesitate to put much trust in a document that ignores it. Additionally, the current version doesn't contain any statement about XHTML at all anymore.

Comment: It does contain a statement, it's just in a different place in the documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html